# Problem with getting while loop to repeat in python

Tags: python, while-loop

Whenever I run this program, I can't get the while loop to repeat. It's a simple exercise with classes and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
class Enemy():
    def attack(self):
        enemy_health = 50
        while enemy_health > 0:
            action = input("attack enemy?")
            if action.lower() == "yes":
                print("enemy health dropped by 5")
                enemy_health =- 5
            else:
                print("enemy escaped!")




jaguar = Enemy()
jaguar.attack()
```

I want the input to repeat until the enemy health is 0. Also, should I include any return statements in here instead of simply subtracting from enemy health? Thank you

Comment: Change this `enemy_health =- 5` to `enemy_health -= 5`.

Comment: You just set the enemy health to -5, should be `enemy_health-=5` or `enemy_health=enemy_health-5`

Comment: A lot of people seem to be saying the same exact thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small mistake, this line:

```
enemy_health =- 5
```

Should actually be:

```
enemy_health -= 5
```

Your original line just sets the health to `-5`. Easier to see the mistake when you change the spacing:

```
enemy_health = -5  # same as the first line
```

Answer (score 0):

When you used `enemy_health =- 5`, you're not decreasing the enemy health by 5, you're *setting* it to - 5. Use `enemy_health -= 5`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have to inverse the operator to `-=`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here:

```
enemy_health =- 5
```

This sets `enemy_health` to -5. What you want to do is take whatever `enemy_health` is and subtract 5 from it and then store that value back in `enemy_health`.

You could do that like this: `enemy_health -= 5`

Or like this: `enemy_health = enemy_health - 5`